# jQuery .focus on the next input field when new fields gets created

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I currently have jQuery set up so when user presses enter in a field, a new set of fields populate. However, the focus is still on the current field. How do I set it up so when someone presses enter, the focus becomes on the new field?

coffee

```
$('.teaser-form').keyup (e) ->
  if e.keyCode == 13
    $('.add-new-list').click()
```

view

```
.nested-fields.gear-patrol
  .col-md-10
    .gear-handler-cover
      = f.text_field :category, class: 'form-control list-category', placeholder: "Category"
  .col-md-2
    = link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, class: 'btn btn-default pull-right'
  .col-md-12
    = f.text_area :list, class: 'form-control', rows: "3", placeholder:'List your items (separated by commas)'
  .col-md-12
    = f.text_field :list, class: 'teaser-form form-control', placeholder: 'testing'
```

[image]

If you see, I typed in the word `enter`, and this is the first set of fields. In this input field, I can press enter, and the others will populate, but my focus stays at the first element.

I want it to be able to focus on the new `.teaser-form` every time enter is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val().trim().length > 0)
      $(this).closest("p").next().find("input").focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<p>Type something and press Enter.</p>
<p><input type="text"></p>
<p><input type="text"></p>
<p><input type="text"></p>
<p><input type="text"></p>
<p><input type="text"></p>
<p><input type="text"></p>
<p><input type="text"></p>
<p><input type="text"></p>
<p><input type="text"></p>
<p><input type="text"></p>
```

This also prevents users from pressing enter on the blank textbox.

Comment: Yes, something similar. But I have that click event, and I tried implementing what you have with it. I don't think I'm doing it right because nothing's happening. The click event will add a new field.

Comment: Which click event should add a new field? I don't have any click events. Am I missing something? @hellomello...

Comment: Sorry, I have a button that's not shown in my example,  but my click event is adding new fields, so I was wondering if you can help me with the code, on how I can focus after a click event

Comment: Just add the button and focus it using the `button.last().focus()`.

Comment: I tried doing this... `$('.add-new-list').click().last(".teaser-form").focus()`, seems like I'm getting closer, should this work? or did I do something wrong?